# Navigate through pages in a paginator using React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pagination

First I want to say this is my first question, sorry if it doesn't meet the standards of a quality one (whether it's too messy / badly organized or explained), I'm listening to all kinds of feedback. Also sorry if my english is not perfect, I'll try to be as understandable as possible.

So here is my problem : I'm implementing a React paginator, compatible with server-side content-range pagination. I want to navigate through pages, when there are too much of them.

A basic example without styling available here (EDIT : working, see answer) : https://codesandbox.io/s/w03lkpmy48

*(I'm a React rookie, so the quality of my code is probably questionable.)*

I created a function `calculateNumberOfPages(itemsCount)` (l.42) where itemsCount can be a huge number, e.g 7683, to return an int used to create the `<li>`s.

In the render, I call this function (l.48) to get the number, then I loop on it x times and push `<li>`s in an array (l.53 to 65).

However, when the itemsCount is huge, that can result in something like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJcAy.png

which is why I put an ellipsis if the number of pages is above 10 :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFi8J.png

Now, the problem is that I want to navigate through pages, to get next pages (4 by 4). If I click on the 10th page, i should have 10 11 12 13 14 ... 16 (for example), and same when I click on the 10th page, in order to have previous pages.

But I'm logically stuck, and I quite need your help. Some comments in the code might point out what I want to do, but they might be as messy as my logic.

If you have other questions, I'm all ears. Thanks for reading my question !

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For React, try https://codesandbox.io/s/new instead of jsfiddle.

Comment: Done, you can find it there : https://codesandbox.io/s/w03lkpmy48

Comment: That's a start. But clicking does nothing, so that's not *complete*. The comments help, but try writing some code — Stack Overflow is for seeking help to make *your* code work. Good luck!

Comment: Okay I had some help from a friend, I have a working version in the sandbox, and I think I can close this question, thanks for your advices, I will try to be clearer next time !

Comment: Great that it's solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I had help from a friend in order to do this.

What was essentially missing in my code was a way to conserve the state of the current page, to compare it. So I added a currentPage property in the state.

Then I added some Javascript (with if/else, needs to be optimized and cleansed) to compare values of the `<li>`s and the current page.

And I change the values displayed in the render.

You can see all of it in the codesandbox in the question !